# tPartitioner, tCollector & tRecollector talend DI

Tags: etl, talend, business-intelligence

I'm new in talend and trying to test tPartitioner, tCollector & tRecollector for processing data in parallel.I'm using the entrprise edition talend data integration 6.0.1 but i can't find these components in palette.Is it because thes components are specific to tallend big data only or what??

Answer (score 0):

In the version 6.5 of Talend DI, these components are under "**Orchestration**" in Palette : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQAcG.png)

You need to check in : **File > Edit Project properties > Designer > Palette Settings** if the **Orchestration** folder in the from **Show** area

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgLXt.png)

Comment: Thank for thereply ,I checked it but i don't find these components .the version is Talend DI 6.0

Comment: Sometimes there are missing components using an Talend Enterprise Edition. They will be available in the Palette of Talend Studio once you subscribe to one of the Talend Platform products not Talend Enterprise for Data Integration